# Redirect Piwik HTTP request to different server

Tags: php, apache, http, matomo

I have Piwik running on one server, Server A. All my websites run on a different server, Server B. I don't want my users to know Server A's address (including any cookies that would be set), but I want it to do all the statistics. I presume I will have to redirect all the requests to piwik.php from Server B to Server A but I don't know how.

Comment: Redirect let your users know Server A's address.

Comment: Well I know that if I use a 301 or 302 that my address will be revealed. That's why I''m asking.

Comment: Hmm, if you know that, then I see no reason to ask because you already know it does not work. also, how could you tell the user to do requests to piwik w/o telling where piwik is. This inherently makes no sense at all.

Comment: Well, I thought I might be able to get the raw HTTP request header, rewrite it and then send it to Server A -- or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
## Piwik Proxy Hide URL
This script allows to track statistics using Piwik, without revealing the
Piwik Server URL. This is useful for users who track multiple websites
on the same Piwik server, but don't want to show the Piwik server URL in 
the source code of all tracked websites.
```

Located in the /path/to/piwik/misc/proxy-hide-piwik-url/ folder.

Should do what your looking for.